# The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I was training a deep learning model but i am encountering the error like The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 1.And also while training the data the accuracy is above 1 that means i am getting the accuracy like 1.04,1.06 like that.
The Below is the Training Code

```
def train(model,criterion,optimizer,iters):
    epoch = iters
    train_loss = []
    validaion_loss = []
    train_acc = []
    validation_acc = []
    states = ['Train','Valid']
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("epoch : {}/{}".format(epoch+1,epochs))
        for phase in states:
            if phase == 'Train':
                model.train()
                dataload = train_data_loader
            else:
                model.eval()
                dataload = valid_data_loader

            run_loss,run_acc = 0,0
            for data in dataload:
                inputs,labels = data
                #print("Inputs:",inputs.shape)
                #print("Labels:",labels.shape)
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                labels = labels.byte()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
            
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'Train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    print("Outputs",outputs.shape)
                    loss = criterion(outputs,labels)
                
                    predict = outputs>=0.5
                    #print("Predict",predict.shape)
                    if phase == 'Train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                    acc = torch.sum(predict == labels.data)

                run_loss+=loss.item()
                #print("Running_Loss",run_loss)
                run_acc+=acc.item()/len(labels)
                #print("Running_Acc",run_acc)
            if phase == 'Train':
                epoch_loss = run_loss/len(train_data_loader)
                train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
                epoch_acc = run_acc/len(train_data_loader)
                train_acc.append(epoch_acc)
            else:
                epoch_loss = run_loss/len(valid_data_loader)
                validaion_loss.append(epoch_loss)
                epoch_acc = run_acc/len(valid_data_loader)
                validation_acc.append(epoch_acc)
        
            print("{}, loss :{},accuracy:{}".format(phase,epoch_loss,epoch_acc))
    
    history = {'Train_loss':train_loss,'Train_accuracy':train_acc,
               'Validation_loss':validaion_loss,'Validation_Accuracy':validation_acc}
    return model,history
```

Below is the code of the base model

```
model = models.resnet34(pretrained = True)

for param in model.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False

model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features,out_features = 1024),nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(in_features = 1024,out_features = 512),nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(0.3),
                         nn.Linear(in_features=512,out_features=256),nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(in_features = 256,out_features = 3),nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1))

device = torch.device("cuda" if cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
model.to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr = 0.00001)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

I tried with predict == labels.unsqueeze(1) it didn't raise any error but the accuracy is going over 1. May I know where i had to change the code.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `output` tensor of the size [32,3] 32 is the number of mini-batches and 3 is the output of your neural network e.g.

```
[[0.25, 0.45, 0.3],
 [0.45, 0.15, 0.4],
      ....
      ....
 [0.2, 0.15, 0.65]]
```

When you compare whether `output` >= 0.5 the result is `predict` tensor but it is `bool` tensor with the same size of output [32,3] like that:

```
[[False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
      ....
      ....
 [False, False, True]]
```

and `Labels` is 0D tensor with 32 values e.g.

```
[0,2,...,0]
```

**The cause of the problem is here: to compare between `predicts` and `labels`, you should select the index of the maximum probability from each row in `predicts` tensor like that:**

```
predicts = predicts.argmax(1) 
# output 
[0,0,...,2]
```

But `predicts` is `bool` tensor, and you cannot apply `argmax` to `bool` tensor directly. Therefore, you got the error message as you indicated in the comment. To solve this problem, you need only to do the following:

```
 predicts = (output >= 0.5)*1
```

Now you can compare between the two tensors `predicts, labels`, because both have the same size.

In brief, you should use:

```
predicts = (output >= 0.5)*1
acc = torch.sum(predicts.argmax(1) == Labels)
```

***Your problem is solved, but the accuracy is logically not correct.***
Therefore, be careful if you want to use sigmoid with multi-classification problem because you use `output >= 0.5` however, you have 3 classes in the output. This is not correct because imagine you have in the output [0.15,0.45,0.4]. Your `predict` will be [0, 0, 0] and then `argmax(1)` will select the first index if there are equal numbers, however, the second index should be selected in this case because it has the largest probability. The best way to do that if you have a multi-classification problem is to use `softmax` instead of `sigmoid (>= 0.5)`.

By the way, if you come back to your model structure (last line), you will find that you already used `nn.LogSoftmax`. You need just to remove this line `predicts = (outputs >= 0.5)` and use directly:

```
#before the for loop
num_corrects  = 0

# inside the for loop
num_corrects = num_corrects  + torch.sum(outputs.argmax(1) == Labels)

#outside the loop
train_accuracy = (100. * num_corrects / len(train_loader.dataset))
```

Comment: After implementing your suggestions i got runtime error as 
RuntimeError: "argmax_cuda" not implemented for 'Bool'

Comment: Hi @Phoenix I tried but the accuracy is remained same throughout the epochs as suggested earlier by maintaining the type of the labels and predict as same.

Comment: I edited my answer after I understood your code deeply

Comment: I didn't get you regarding usage of softmax could you please elaborate it a little or a piece of code i had to change regarding accuracy problem

Comment: Thanks Man You are the savior 

Comment: I updated the answer to calculate the correct accuracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242883/discussion-between-helloworld8688-and-phoenix).